# How can I fix "TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to get my **kick command** running, but if I want to test it, I'm getting this **error**:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined
        at Client.<anonymous> (E:\BlackLion\src\index.js:87:34)
        at Client.emit (node:events:394:28)
        at MessageCreateAction.handle (E:\BlackLion\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
        at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (E:\BlackLion\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)        
        at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (E:\BlackLion\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
        at WebSocketShard.onPacket (E:\BlackLion\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
        at WebSocketShard.onMessage (E:\BlackLion\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
        at WebSocket.onMessage (E:\BlackLion\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
        at WebSocket.emit (node:events:394:28)
        at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (E:\BlackLion\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:825:20)
```

This is my **index.js**:

```js
require('dotenv').config();
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const client = new Discord.Client();
let randomNumber;
prefix = "!";
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
var glume = []

function getJockes() {
    random(15);
    joke = glume[randomNumber];
    console.log(randomNumber);
    console.log(joke);
}

function random(number) {
    randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * number + 1);
}

function getQuote() {
    return fetch("https://zenquotes.io/api/random")
        .then(res => {
            return res.json()
        })
        .then(data => {
            return data[0]["q"] + " -" + data[0]["a"]
        })
}

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`)
})

client.on("message", async msg => {

    if (msg.author.bot) return;
    if (!msg.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;


    //comenzi basic
    if (msg.content.startsWith(prefix + "inspire")) {
        getQuote().then(quote => msg.channel.send(quote))
        console.log('inspire');
    }
    if (msg.content.startsWith(prefix + "ping")) {
        msg.channel.send("pong");
        console.log('Ping-Pong');
    }
    if (msg.content.startsWith(prefix + "zar")) {
        random(6);
        console.log(randomNumber);
        msg.channel.send(randomNumber);
    }
    if (msg.content.startsWith(prefix + "cappajura")) {
        random(2);
        console.log(randomNumber);
        if (randomNumber === 1) {
            msg.channel.send("Cap");
        }
        else {
            msg.channel.send("Pajura");
        }
    }
    if (msg.content.startsWith(prefix + 'glume')) {
        getJockes();
        msg.channel.send(joke);
    }
    if (msg.content.startsWith(prefix + "kick")) {
        client.commands.get('kick').execute(msg, args);
    }
})
client.login(process.env.DISCORDJS_BOT_TOKEN)
```

The error occurs in this row:

> `client.commands.get('kick').execute(msg, args);`

And this is **kick.js**:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'kick',
    description: 'kick people',
    execute(msg, args) {
        const channel = '858963360909099068';
        const impostor = msg.mentions.members.first();
        const member = msg.author.id;
        let botResponse;
        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#f9ae0e')
            .setTitle('Kick')
            .setDescription(botResponse)
            .addFields(
                { Impostor: impostor },
                { KickAuthor: member }
            );
        let messageEmbed = await msg.channel.send(embed);

        client.on("message", msg => {
            if (msg.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'ADMIN')) {
                if (!impostor) {
                    botResponse = 'You need to tag the person that you want to be kicked';
                    msg.channel.send(embed);
                }
                else {
                    botResponse = impostor.displayName + " was succesfully kicked";
                    msg.channel.send(embed);
                }
            }
            else {
                botResponse = 'You are not able to kick people';
                msg.channel.send(embed);
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: And `console.log()` your `client.commands.get('kick')` and check if it's empty

Comment: i tried it @Toasty but still the same error :(

Comment: If you log `client.commands.get('kick')`, is it empty or not?

Comment: Where do you **set** your commands? (e.g. `client.commands.set(command.name, command);`). If you want to **get** a command you have to **set** it first. Take a look at the [official guide](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/#individual-command-files)

Comment: i tried to add console.log(client.commands.get('kick') and in console it said undefined @Toasty

Comment: That's because you never **set** the command. As I said in the comment before, look at the guide. This should fix your problem